# NHibernate fluent mapping - specify tables at runtime?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

**Question:**
How can I pass a string representing a table name to an NHibernate ClassMap?

**Details:**
I have several databases which are *almost* the same, with some minor variations in table and view names.  I would like to be able to handle these variations via configuration parameters in my app.config file.  For example, I could specify the table names for a particular configuration using the following custom section:

```
<tableNames>
    <add key="logicalTable1" value="ACTUAL_TABLE_1"/>
    <add key="logicalTable2" value="ACTUAL_TABLE_2"/>
</tablenames>
```

Now, if I load these config parameters at runtime, how do I get the table name into the ClassMap (i.e.,

```
public class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public class MyClassMap()
    {
         Table("ACTUAL_TABLE_1");   // <--- HERE I WANT Table(logicaTable1) 
    ...
}
```

**Note**: I am using Ninject to inject ISessionFactory -- not sure if this matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you could just use the `ConfigurationManager` class:

```
public class MyClassMap()
{
  var table = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logicalTable2"];
  Table(table);
...
}
```

Your project would need to reference the `System.Configuration` assembly.

**Update:**

Or use a "TableNameProvider" class:

```
public interface ITableNameProvider
{
        string LogicalTable1 { get; }
}

public class TableNameProvider : ITableNameProvider
{
        public string LogicalTable1 { get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logicalTable1"]; } }
}
```

I'm not sure about exactly how to do this with Ninject, but assuming its like other containers:

```
public class MyClassMap()
{
  var provider = GetMyContainer().GetInstance<ITableProvider>();
  var table = provider.LogicalTable1;
  Table(table);
...
}
```

This way you would just need to change your TableNameProvider class.

I'm not sure if you could inject a MappingFactory or something into Fluent-NHibernate to handle mapping file dependencies and true injection. Something to look into.

Comment: My only hesitation with that is that it's essentially creating a dependency on a global object.  For example, the custom section is a NamedValueFileSectionHandler -- what if I wanted to change that down the road? This would require modification of every mapping class.

Comment: Interesting method. I didn't know the `ITableNameProvider` existed. I was going to suggest that the mapping classes could have a public property which allowed the table to be set, and you could simply override the property before constructing the `SessionFactory`.

Comment: `ITableProvider` does not exist, its just an interface to use with my implementation above.